# Strange location of panels

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a program which is some kind of tests. In this test, I have function `AddQuestion` that adds one panel with question. To place these panels one by one, I have a variable `loc` that saves location of next panel. First two `Panel`'s with questions adds correct, but next ones are located wrong(far away at the bottom). What can it be?

```
public void AddQuestion(int number, Question quest)
        {
            Panel p = new Panel();
            p.Name = "panel" + (number);
            p.Size = new Size(550, 400);
            p.Location = new Point(40, loc);
            p.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Bisque;
            p.AutoScroll = true;
            Panel pict_block = new Panel();
            pict_block.Size = new Size(480, 200);
            pict_block.Location = new Point(10, 10);
            PictureBox pict = new PictureBox();
            pict.Image = quest.image;
            pict.Size = new Size(240, 180);
            pict.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
            pict.Location = new Point(130, 1);
            pict_block.Controls.Add(pict);
            p.Controls.Add(pict_block);

            Label number_text = new Label(); //номер питання
            number_text.Text = "Питання № " + number ;
            number_text.Font = new Font("Aria", 8, FontStyle.Bold);
            number_text.AutoSize = false;
            number_text.Location = new Point(400, 210);
            p.Controls.Add(number_text);

            Label q_text = new Label(); // текст питання
            q_text.Text = quest.question_text;
            q_text.Font = new Font("Aria", 9, FontStyle.Bold);
            q_text.AutoSize = false;
            q_text.Size = new Size(400, 50);
            q_text.Location = new Point(5, 220);
            p.Controls.Add(q_text);
            int iter = q_text.Location.Y + 60;
            if (CheckIfMuliple(number))
            {
                foreach (string key in quest.answers.Keys)
                {
                    CheckBox rb = new CheckBox();
                    rb.Text = key;
                    rb.AutoSize = true;
                    rb.Size = new Size(300, 25);
                    rb.Location = new Point(q_text.Location.X + 15, iter);
                    iter += 30;
                    p.Controls.Add(rb);
                }

            }
            else
                {
                    foreach (string key in quest.answers.Keys)
                    {
                        RadioButton rb = new RadioButton();
                        rb.Text = key;
                        rb.Size = new Size(300, 25);
                        rb.AutoSize = true;
                        rb.Location = new Point(q_text.Location.X + 10, iter);
                        iter += 30;
                        p.Controls.Add(rb);
                    }
                }
            questions_panel.Controls.Add(p);
            loc += 450;

        }
```

Good location:
[image]

Bad Location:
[image]

Also I noticed that when I add some panels, then scrool at the middle of the form and add new question, it's not located at the bottom, but somewhere at the center. From next screenshot, 6 question and then 15 question:
[image]

Comment: Can you post an image to show what exactly your problem looks like?

Comment: Where is `loc` defined and is it correct?

Comment: BanksySan, 'loc' is declared as a member of form at the top: int loc = 20;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting this right manually is very difficult.

I suggest that you change `questions_panel` to a [TableLayoutPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.aspx). It takes care of positioning new controls automatically for you.

> **TableLayoutPanel**
>
> Represents a panel that dynamically lays out its contents in a grid
>   composed of rows and columns.

Comment: Can you advise me on: How to change the interval between two panels(questions) in TableLayoutPanel?

Comment: Try modifying the Margin property of the controls added to the Layout

Answer (score 4):

```
    p.Location = new Point(40, loc);
```

This will not work correctly when the outer panel is scrolled.  You have to offset it by the that panel's scroll position.  Fix:

```
   p.Location = new Point(40  + questions_panel.AutoScrollPosition.X,
                          loc + questions_panel.AutoScrollPosition.Y);
```

---

```
   loc += 450;
```

This will not work correctly when your program runs on a machine with a video adapter that runs with a different dots-per-inch setting.  Pretty common these days, modern versions of Windows make it *very* easy to change.  The panel will automatically be rescaled to match the DPI setting.  Fix:

```
  loc += p.Height + 50;
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to duplicate your problem, and was able to fix it by always offsetting the top of the new Panel based on the location of the last panel. I changed your code:

```
questions_panel.Controls.Add(p);
loc += 450;
```

to:

```
if (questions_panel.Controls.Count > 0)
{
    //Location of Top of last panel added then offset vertically by 450
    p.Location = new Point(p.Location.X, questions_panel.Controls[questions_panel.Controls.Count-1].Location.Y +450);
    questions_panel.Controls.Add(p);
}
else
    questions_panel.Controls.Add(p);
```